# how set cols in TextareaAutosize In the form of responsive?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

how set cols in TextareaAutosize In the form of responsive

```
<TextareaAutosize aria-label="minimum height" rowsMin={3} placeholder="Minimum 3 rows" />
```

Be responsive according to the pages that are located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a variable set the width and use this variable as props in TextareaAutosize component just like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextareaAutosize from '@material-ui/core/TextareaAutosize';
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";

const styles={
  width: "100%"
}

export default function MinHeightTextarea() {
  return <Container><TextareaAutosize aria-label="minimum height" style={styles} rowsMin={3} placeholder="Minimum 3 rows" /></Container>;
}
```

Check this demo for more: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-sbg8b?file=/demo.js

Comment: @A.R.SEIF try adding <Container/> component by wrapping around TextareaAutosize and then check.

Comment: @A.R.SEIF check my latest code on code-sandbox link. Just add width: 100% to your styles object. Rest everything remains the same in above code. Try to resize your browser to see the effect.

Comment: I am glad my answer was helpful to you.